# Is usage of the word epitome in a negative sense correct?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Can the word epitome be used in a negative context like in this statement

> He is the epitome of corruption.

And should I be using *the* epitome instead of *an* epitome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one could say "He is **the epitome** of corruption".

> Indifference, to me, is the epitome of evil.

*Elie Wiesel, in US News & World Report (27 October 1986)*

When it is phrased 'an epitome' the noun refers to its second meaning of 'a condensed account', as in:

> In the first part the greatest freedom has been used in reducing the narration into a narrow compass, so that it is by no means a translation but **an epitome**, in which, whether everything either useful or entertaining be comprised, the compiler is least qualified to determine.

*[A Voyage to Abyssinia](http://lobo.thefreelibrary.com/Voyage-to-Abyssinia/1-1#epitome) by Father Lobo, translated by M. Le Grand*

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of [a perfect example](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epitome)

It could be used for something positive or negative.

As to the definite or indefinite article, it depends on the context.....you will see the epitome more frequently in colloquial usage.